# Bing Maps not working properly on BlackBerry

Tags: javascript, web, blackberry, bing-maps

I am creating a simple web application using Bing Maps. When I load the application in BlackBerry Z30, the route drawn between the start and end destination is getting distorted. Please find the attached screenshot. 
But this works perfectly fine on all Samsung devices. Is there any work around to make it work for BlackBerry ?
Below is the sample code which I use to draw the line between start and end destinations.

```
function drawRouteShape(points, color){             
    var cfg = {    
        strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(255,100,0,100), 
        strokeThickness: 5
     };

     this.map.entities.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline(points, cfg));
};
```

`points` is the array of lat and longs. A sample screenshot:

[image: Sample screenshot]

Attached is the code in my index.html. This is my whole index.html of this sample app where you can easily reproduce the issue in Blackberry browser.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      function GetMap()
      {   

         map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), 
                           {credentials: "Ai2jw9BTQAIwRGYifdh",
                            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(48.76767, 9.171919),
                            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
                            mapViewRestriction:Microsoft.Maps.Map.OneWorldOnly,
                            zoom: 7});

             console.log("Microsoft.Maps.Map.OneWorldOnly = " + Microsoft.Maps.Map.OneWorldOnly);               
              var start = {
                 latitude: 49.201809,
                 longitude: 9.50106

               };
               var start2 = {
                 latitude: 49.202451999999994,longitude:9.501092

               };
                var start3 = {
                 latitude: 49.20245799999999,longitude:9.50128
               };
                var start4 = {
                 latitude: 49.20238799999999,longitude:9.504112

               };
                var start5 = {
                 latitude: 49.20225899999999,longitude:9.504631999999999

               };
                var start6 = {
                 latitude: 49.20170099999999,longitude:9.506010999999999

               };
                var start7 = {
                 latitude: 49.201620999999996,longitude:9.505941

               };
                var start8 = {
                 latitude: 49.200258,longitude:9.505641

               };
                var start9 = {
                 latitude: 49.199191,longitude:9.505217

               };
                var start10 = {
                 latitude: 49.198831,longitude:9.505271
               };
                var start11 = {
                latitude: 49.198240999999996,longitude:9.505732

               };
                var start12 = {
                 latitude: 49.197967999999996,longitude:9.505791

               };
                var start13 = {
                 latitude: 49.197641,longitude:9.505700000000001

               };
                var start14 = {
                 latitude: 49.197029,longitude:9.505367000000001

               };
                var start15 = {
                 latitude: 49.196938,longitude:9.505121

               };
                var start16 = {
                latitude: 49.197142,longitude:9.50364

               };
                var start17 = {
                 latitude: 49.197351,longitude:9.502712

               };
                var start18 = {
                 latitude: 49.197818,longitude:9.501328

               };
                var start19 = {
                latitude: 49.197871,longitude:9.500411000000001

               };
                var start20 = {
                latitude: 49.197378,longitude:9.500378000000001
               };
                var start21 = {
                 latitude:49.196192,longitude:9.500389000000002

               };
                var start22 = {
                latitude: 49.195768,longitude:9.500309000000001

               };
                var start23 = {
                 latitude: 49.1927,longitude:9.499011000000001

               };
                var start24 = {
                latitude: 49.192711,longitude:9.498941000000002

               };
                var start25 = {
                 latitude: 49.192609000000004,longitude:9.498742000000002

               };
                var start26 = {
                 latitude: 49.192491000000004,longitude:9.498780000000002

               };
                var start27 = {
                 latitude: 49.19244200000001,longitude:9.498919000000003

               };
                var start28 = {
                 latitude:49.19211000000001,longitude:9.498817000000003

               };
                var start29 = {
                latitude:49.19115000000001,longitude:9.498699000000002

               };
                var start30 = {
                latitude: 49.19030200000001,longitude:9.498828000000001

               };
                var start31 = {
                 latitude: 49.18958900000001,longitude:9.499091000000002

               };
                var start32 = {
                 latitude:49.18869800000001,longitude:9.499660000000002

               };
                var start33 = {
                 latitude: 49.18818800000001,longitude:9.500142000000002

               };
                var start34 = {
                 latitude: 49.18751800000001,longitude:9.500969000000001

               };
                var start35 = {
                 latitude: 49.185699000000014,longitude:9.504010000000001

               };
                var start36 = {
               latitude: 49.185158000000015,longitude:9.504761

               };
                var start37 = {
                 latitude: 49.184272000000014,longitude:9.505668

               };
                var start38 = {
                 latitude: 49.18345200000002,longitude:9.50622

               };
                 var start39 = {
                 latitude: 49.183591000000014,longitude:9.506767

               };
                var start40 = {
                 latitude: 49.18374100000001,longitude:9.508189

               };
                var start41 = {
               latitude: 49.183650000000014,longitude:9.508731

               };
                var start42 = {
                 latitude: 49.183371000000015,longitude:9.509127999999999

               };
                var start43 = {
                 latitude: 49.180748000000015,longitude:9.509738999999998

               };
                var start44 = {
                 latitude: 49.18036200000002,longitude:9.509706999999999

               };
                var start45 = {
                 latitude: 49.18036200000002,longitude:9.510297

               };
               var start46 = {
                 latitude: 49.180458000000016,longitude:9.511858

               };


              updateStartPin(start);
              updateDestPin(start46);
        var points= [start,start2,start3,start4,start5,start6,start7,start8,start9,start10,start11,start12,start13,start14,start15,start16,start17,start18,start19,start20,start21,start22,start23,start24,start25,start26,start27,start28,start29,start30,start31,start32,start33,start34,start35,start36,start37,start38,start39,start40,start41,start42,start43,start44,start45,start46];

        var color = {blue: 6,
                    green: 232,
                    red: 187};
         drawRouteShape(points, color);

      };

       function  updateStartPin(point) {

            var startPinOptions = {
                icon:this.startIconImg,
                width:this.startIconWidth,
                height:this.startIconHeight,
                zIndex: 50
            };
            this.startPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(point, startPinOptions);

            console.log("Set start pin");
            this.map.entities.push(this.startPin);
        };

        function updateDestPin(point) {
         console.log("pointdest = " + point);

        var destPinOptions = {
            icon:this.destIconImg,
            width:this.destIconWidth,
            height:this.destIconHeight,
            zIndex: 50
        };


        };
        function drawRouteShape(points, color){

          var cfg = {
            //strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(255, color.red, color.green, color.blue),
            strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(255,100,0,100), 
            strokeThickness: 5
        };

         this.map.entities.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline(points, cfg));


        };

      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
      <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:1920px; height:1080px;"></div>       
   </body>
</html>
```

This is my whole index.html of this sample app where you can easily reproduce the issue in blackberry browser
    }

Comment: Please help to understand about this issue ?

Comment: As a starting point try to see if you can reproduce this with one of the samples: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Shapes1 If you can reproduce it with the samples then the issue is likely with the browser in the Blackberry Z30 browser. If it does work then post code a more complete code sample so we can see if you have the proper metadata, doctype and CSS styles for the map.

Comment: The issue is reproducible only if there are lot of lat long points near to each other. I am attaching the index.html of my sample project. The issue is reproducible with the same hard coded lat and long in the code. Is there any configuration to be added to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of test (12 different browsers) I've found that this renders on every single browser I tested correctly. I don't have access to a blackberry Z30, but since all the browsers I tested worked (old and new) the only logical reason for this issue is a rendering issue in the browser in Blackberry Z30. The polyline in Bing Maps is nothing more than an svg image. The only time I get anything that looks similar to what you showed was when I was zoomed out a lot and the thickness of the polyline made it looked like a filled polygon, but as you zoom in this is corrected. As a test try running this HTML in the browser. This is the generated SVG image in Bing Maps of your line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%"><path style="pointer-events: visiblePainted;" fill="none" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#640064" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" d="M 573 99 L 573 88 L 575 88 L 608 89 L 614 91 L 630 101 L 630 103 L 626 127 L 621 146 L 622 153 L 627 163 L 628 168 L 627 174 L 623 185 L 620 186 L 603 183 L 592 179 L 576 171 L 565 170 L 565 178 L 565 200 L 564 207 L 549 262 L 548 262 L 546 264 L 546 266 L 548 266 L 547 272 L 545 290 L 547 305 L 550 317 L 556 333 L 562 342 L 572 354 L 607 387 L 616 396 L 626 412 L 633 427 L 639 424 L 656 422 L 662 423 L 667 428 L 674 475 L 674 482 L 680 482 L 699 480" /></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: YES.. the above HTML renders fine in my blackberry browser. Real issue is encountered only when I zoom the map in blackberry. So is there any way to fix this issue which occurs while zooming ? I even reduced the stroke thickness too...but no luck..even used strokeDashArray...

Comment: Very odd as I pulled this SVG right out of the generated HTML of Bing Maps. So it only occurs when you are zooming, not when the map is done zooming?

Comment: It occurs even after the map is done with the zooming. I have taken the screenshot after the map has been zoomed. Any solution available ? This occurs even on other blackberry devices as well, so not just in Z30.

Comment: This is a very strange issue that I haven't heard of before. I'm asking around internally to see if anyone has come across this.

Comment: I've had a couple different people look into this and test it on blackberries. No one was able to reproduce this issue. Unless the code you are using is slightly different from what is in this thread this issue is due to a bug in the Blackberry browser your using.

Comment: The code is exactly the same I am using.Did you try zooming in and out. I tried in multiple blackberry devices and was able to reproduce the issue on zooming the map.

Comment: We tried zooming in/out, panning for a while and it always rendered correctly on all the blackberry devices we tested.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try in Blackberry Z 30  ? Just want to confirm it is a device browser issue.

Comment: I had others test. It worked on Z10. Not sure about Z30.

Comment: You are the only person I have come across that can reproduce this issue. There isn't an issue in the Bing Maps control. If there is an issue it's with the browser in Blackberry.

Comment: I got this reproduced even in Z10. Please do a zoom to the maximum level and you can see the issue with the above attached current code.

Comment: This has been tested by several people on different BlackBerry devices including the Z10 and was unreproducible. Even if it was, the issue is with the blackberry browser and has to be fixed by blackberry.